# I want to open the tutorial page only one time in my application. How to achieve this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

App delegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

{
    BOOL isFirst;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL isFirst;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSUserDefaults *Defaults;
```

App delegate.m  file

```
Defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"default:%@",[Defaults valueForKey:@"introscreen"]);
```

-- here am getting the OFF value only

```
if(isFirst)
{
    [Defaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"introscreen"];
    [Defaults synchronize];
}
else
{     
    [Defaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"introscreen"];
    [Defaults synchronize];

}

NSLog(@"default:%@",[Defaults valueForKey:@"introscreen"]);
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
-(Void)Finish
{
    appDelegate.isFirst=NO;
    NSLog(@"default:%@",[Defaults valueForKey:@"introscreen"]);
}
```

I am using defaults to store the value of the intro screen. 

If the Defaults is On the Intro screen should appear otherwise it won't appear. For that I have used the Bool variable in the app delegate.
Every time I am getting "Off" only. Someone Help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Defaults` property won't have a persistent store.

Delete the property and use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` instead.